# PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "."

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try create postgresql query, for get the same data from different tables, but when execute I have error. In mysql I did something like that query

```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
  LINE 4:                             `B`.`_id` AS `_id`
                                         ^
> Time: 0.02s
```

my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
      `B`.`_id` AS `_id`
  FROM ( 
      SELECT 
       `apdi`.`id` AS `_id`               
      FROM `application_person_document_image` AS `apdi`
      INNER JOIN `application_person_document` AS `apd` ON `apdi`.`id` = `apd`.`application_person_document_id`
      INNER JOIN `application_person` AS `ap` ON `ap`.`id` = `apd`.`application_person_id`
      INNER JOIN `application` AS `a` ON `a`.`id` = `ap`.`application_id`   
      WHERE
      `a`.`id` = 196733                            
  ) AS `B`
  GROUP BY `B`.`_id`

UNION

  SELECT
      `N`.`_id` AS `_id`                        
  FROM (
      SELECT
       `app`.`id` AS `_id`,
      FROM `application_person_photo` AS `app`
      INNER JOIN `application_person` AS `ap` ON `ap`.`id` = `app`.`application_person_id`
      INNER JOIN `application` AS `a` ON `a`.`id` = `ap`.`application_id`
      WHERE
      `a`.`id` = 196733                             
  ) AS `N`
  GROUP BY `N`.`_id`
) AS t
```

What's wrong ? I looked documentation, using aliases exist.

Comment: backtick is not an escape character in postgre

Comment: you are rigth, but how to protect from sql injection ?

Comment: backticks does not prevent for SQL-injection

Comment: SQL injection is indeed a completely different thing. Backticks seems to be all the rage in MySQL world for some reason but they don’t really do anything (unless you name your tables/columns badly). For injection you can find a lot of information on the web, the most important thing is to use parameters and not play around trying to escape things yourself.

Comment: Remove those backticks; they are invalid in SQL (and no, replacing them with the SQL standard's double quotes will not prevent you from SQL injection either)

Comment: See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) about the correct usage of quoted identifiers.

Comment: ok, thnks, I will using double quotes

Comment: You should avoid quoted identifiers to begin with. They don't solve any problems and create more problems than they are worth.

Comment: @Jens: it's [Postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_PostgreSQL.3F_How_is_it_pronounced.3F_What_is_Postgres.3F) not "postgre"